# HERE Reverse Geocoding: Trying to request LinkInfo By LinkId/MapReferenceId

Tags: geocoding, here-api

I've been using the HERE Reverse Geocoding endpoint (example URL below) to convert latlons into Location data (works a treat, thanks!).

[https://reverse.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?pos={lat},{lon},0&mode=trackPosition&app_id={myId}&app_code={myCode}&maxresults=1&locationattributes=linkInfo](https://reverse.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?pos=%7Blat%7D,%7Blon%7D,0&mode=trackPosition&app_id=%7BmyId%7D&app_code=%7BmyCode%7D&maxresults=1&locationattributes=linkInfo)

I was wondering if there is a way to send a request for the same/a similar response as the above URL but passing LinkId/MapReferenceId (I believe the two are interchangeable) instead of pos=,?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't exactly an answer, but the question no longer needs to remain open - I found a workaround my end that removes the need for this endpoint.